# How to fix white gaps in spectrograms when converting .wav files to spectrograms in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, wav, spectrogram

I'm trying to convert .wav files to spectrograms using matplotlib (plt.specgram). It worked, but there are some big white lines passing vertically through the spectrogram. I looked at the samples array (which is loaded from the wavfile.read method) and saw that there were a lot of values set to 0 for some reason, which results in thick white lines being drawn to the spectrogram.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these lines? I'm pretty new to working with audio files in Python so I'm a little lost. Is it a problem with the code or is the data in the .wav file bad?

Here's the code and the resulting spectrogram:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy.io import wavfile

audio_path = "Audio_Files/"

sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read(audio_path + "0.wav")
segmentSize = 2
seconds = samples.shape[0] / sample_rate

segments = seconds / segmentSize
samplesPerSegment = int(samples.shape[0] / segments)

print("File length: " + str(samples.shape[0] / sample_rate) + " seconds")

plt.specgram(samples[0:samplesPerSegment],Fs=sample_rate, mode='psd')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with a random wav file.

Comment: presumably you have some NaN in those wav files as well?

Comment: Ok, so I'm assuming that the problem lies in the wav file by now. How would I replace those NaN values with something that can be displayed on the spectrogram (if there's a way in the first place)?

Answer (score 0):

encontered the same problem.don't have a perfect way to solve this.But I did find a way to get rid of the white gaps.
Try adding a small random array to your wav/samples.

```
    randarray=np.random.randint(-1,1,len(wav))
    wav=wav+randarray
    plt.specgram(wav)
```

Comment: Make sure spelling and text formatting is correct. That improves readibility a lot